# WPF: RadioButton do not raise event when its load

Tags: wpf

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton Content="A" GroupName="ASD"
                     Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"
                     IsChecked="True"/>
        <RadioButton Content="B" GroupName="ASD"
                     Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"/>
        <RadioButton Content="C" GroupName="ASD"
                     Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ICommand _buttonCommand;
        public ICommand ButtonCommand { get { return (_buttonCommand ?? new BaseCommand(MyAction)); } }

        public void MyAction()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("clicked");
        }
    }
```

**BaseCommand.cs**

```
public class BaseCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action _action;

        public BaseCommand(Action action)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object? parameter)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
```

When I click the button, call MyAction() and print "clicked", It works right.
When the window is loaded, I want its raise event click, call to MyAction() and print "clicked", so I set the first radiobutton IsChecked property = true, but it do not raise event. Why? And how to solve it, thanks.

Comment: Because `ButtonCommand` is not a handler for `Clicked` , `Checked` or `Unchecked` event.

Comment: But when I click it, it works fine. Now I want when the window is loaded, radiobutton with IsChecked property true, raise its event, call function MyAction(), and print "clicked". How do I do that?

Comment: As long you have no real UI testing ambitions, there's no need to raise events manually. You have your initial value that is "checked", which you may want. And you may want initialization, that is performed in MyAction(). I recommend, not sending "clicks" for initial stuff, instead, you could just invoke your click handler-code in your Loaded handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events and commands are not the same. `RadioButoon` has many events to reflect input events or state changes, but can invoke only a single command.

To know the available events visit the API class reference of the class e.g. by moving the cursor on the class name and then pressing "F1": [RadioButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.radiobutton?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#events).

In your case you must handle the `RadioButton.Checked` event. Note that this event will be raised during the initialization routine of the `RadioButton` in order to fetch the local `IsChecked` value. If you really need wait until the button is loaded in framework terms (which means layout calculations and rendering have completed), you can defer the `Checked` event using the `Dispatcher` with a `DispatcherPriority.Loaded` or directly handle the `RadioButton.Loaded` event (instead of the `Checked` event alongside using the `Dispatcher`):

```xml
<RadioButton Content="A"
             GroupName="ASD"
             Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
             Loaded="RadioButton_Loaded"
             IsChecked="True" />
```

```cs
private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
  // Handle IsChecked changed
  radionButton.Command.Execute(default);

  // Alternatively, wait until the control has loaded (in case you need to reference layout related properties)
  this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
  {
    radionButton.Command.Execute(default);
  }, DispatcherPriority.Loaded);

  // If this is a one-time operation, unregister the event handler
  radioButton.Checked -= RadioButton_Checked;
}
```

As mentioned before, if you need the `RadioButton` to be completely loaded, consider to handle the `RadioButton.Loaded` event instead of using the `Dispatcher`.